# How to push a variable number of datasets to a chart data, without the _observer "magic"_ (using vuecharts.js)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, observers, vue-chartjs

I am using charts.js for Vue and trying to push a variable number of datasets (that contain backgroundColour, data and label) to a chart. The data object should log something like this:

[image]

However the datasets are logging an extra observer object, and the charts are not rendering.
This is my code:

```
   let dynamicDataCollection = [];
        for (i =0; i < allDeptNames.length; i++) {
            let datasets = [
                {
                label: allDeptNames[i],
                backgroundColor: barColours[i],
                data: [spaceIterationIns[i].length] 
                }
            ]
            dynamicDataCollection.push(datasets);
        }
        that.datacollection2 = {
            labels: ['Weekly'],                
            datasets: [                              
            ]
        }
        that.datacollection2.datasets = dynamicDataCollection;
        console.log(that.datacollection2);
```

this is my data object:

```
data () {
    return {
        windowWidth: 0,
        windowHeight: 0,
        datacollection2: null,
        chartData: { 

        }, chartOptions: {

        }         
    }
},
```

this is my template:

```
     <charts  v-if="last7DaysSelected" ref="visits_per_dept_bar"
             :css-classes="'visitsChart_bar'" 
             :chart-id="'visits_per_dept_bar'" 
             :height="150" 
             :options="chartOptions"
             :chart-data="datacollection2" 

      ></charts>
```

this is my chart.js

```
import {Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
Chart.defaults.global
let chartOptions = Chart.defaults.global;
chartOptions.defaultFontFamily= "-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif"

const { reactiveProp } = mixins
export default {
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['options'],

  mounted () {
    let that = this;

    that.chartOptions = { 
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                suggestedMin: 0,      
            },       
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                suggestedMin: 0,    
            },
        }],
    },
    legend: {
        labels: {
            fontColor: 'rgb(168, 119, 181)',
        }
    }
  },
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, that.chartOptions)
  }
}
```

and this is the object I'm getting...
[image: the vue Observer object is prying]

Expanded view:
[image: Expanded view]

It's obvious Vue is trying to work its magic but does that mean I can't render my chart with a variable number of datasets?
It's too perilous to prevent the {_ ob _} object. I have tried it and the vue.charts.js program needs some reactivity).
Is there any way to do this? Maybe a trick that allows going through that *for loop* inside the *datacollection2* object? instead of pushing the dataset objects to the *datacollection2*? any thoughts?

Comment: https://github.com/samuelantonioli/vue-static or https://github.com/rpkilby/vue-nonreactive look like they'd do the trick for you.

Comment: copuld you share your data object

Comment: I shared my data object.

Comment: @ceejayoz I have tried the vue static component and it doesn't work. the Datasets program from vue chart.js was written to be reactive and it's precisely that variable/object that I need to push to the dataCollection object. if I force that to be static the chart will not update (it complains it can set property _meta to a string)... but thanks anyway. could be a useful tool for another situation

Comment: There is no need for any external libraries - this is pre-built within Vue ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [options](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options) instead:

```
name: 'myComponent',
data: () {
  return {
    some: 'properties'
  }
},
nonReactiveData: {
  whatever: 'you like'
}
```

This basically creates your component with an `option` named `nonReactiveData`. Then you could use it in your html like:

```
<some-component :data="$options.nonReactiveData">
```

Or if you need it in your script:

```
methods: {
  someMethod() {
    console.log(this.$options.nonReactiveData)
  }
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hi. That's good to know but like I said before on my reply to @ceejayoz i believe the _datasets_ program from __vue chart.js__ was written to be reactive and it's precisely that variable/object that I need to push to the dataCollection object. But thanks anyway, this is related, and it could be a useful tool for some other situation so I have given your answer an up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by concatenating the dynamicDataCollection Object:

```
     that.dynamicDataCollection = [];
        for (i =0; i < allDeptNames.length; i++) {
            let datasets = [
                {
                label: allDeptNames[i],
                backgroundColor: barColours[i],
                data: [spaceIterationIns[i].length] 
                }
            ]
            that.dynamicDataCollection.push(datasets);
        }
// here
        let dynamicFlat = [].concat.apply([], that.dynamicDataCollection)  
        that.datacollection2 = {
            labels: ['Weekly'],                
            datasets: [                           
            ]
        }
// and then here
        that.datacollection2.datasets = dynamicFlat;
```